# \tikzset with multiple arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to use tikzset with multiple arguments.  I've tried to follow the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231701/tikzset-key-with-multiple-arguments), but it's not working (error is

> ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfkeys@temp

).  Here is my latex code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\tikzset{newbox/.style={draw, rectangle, inner sep = 1.5em, fill=white,
%    label={[align=left,shift={(-12ex,3.5ex)}]south east:#1,north
%      west:{\color{red} #2}}} n args={2}}
\tikzset{oldbox/.style={draw, rectangle, inner sep = 1.5em, fill=white,
    label={[align=left,shift={(-12ex,3.5ex)}]south east:{\color{blue}#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [oldbox={$\alpha$}] at (-1,-1) (working) {};
%\node [newbox={a}{b}] at (0,0) (fails) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will compile, but when I uncomment things, it breaks.  I want `newbox` to take 2 arguments.  Please recognize I'm not particularly skilled with tikz - there seem to be multiple ways to do everything, so I've picked up bits and pieces, but never had time to seriously try to understand the whole manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the more refined definition.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{newbox/.style n args=2{draw, rectangle, inner sep = 1.5em, fill=white,
    label={[align=left,anchor=south east]south west:#1},
    label={[align=left,anchor=north east,text=blue]north west:#2}},
    %
    oldbox/.style={draw, rectangle, inner sep = 1.5em, fill=white,
    label={[align=left,anchor=south east,text=blue]south west:#1}}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [oldbox={$\alpha$}] at (-2,-2) (working) {};
\node [newbox={a}{b}] at (0,0) (fails) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just checking - was it a typo to have `south east` and then `south west` immediately after?  Is the `east` part getting obliterated?

Comment: @Joel: It depends on where you want that label. I did not understand the requirement. So I just showed how you can avoid those `shift` commands there. The `east` part is not obliterated.

Answer (score 6):

You're after `style 2 args`, as opposed to just `style`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{newbox/.style 2 args={
              draw, rectangle, inner sep = 1.5em, fill=white,
              label={[blue,align=left,shift={(-12ex,5.5ex)}]south east:#1},
              label={[red]north west:{#2}}
               },
    oldbox/.style={draw, rectangle, inner sep = 1.5em, fill=white,
    label={[align=left,shift={(-12ex,3.5ex)}]south east:{\color{blue}#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [oldbox={$\alpha$}] at (-1,-1) (working) {};
\node [newbox={a}{b}] at (0,0) (fails) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]