# Remove all space around the figure and make it as wide as text width without changing font size

Tags: pgfplots

I am producing two figures with the **pgfplots** package, where one is on top and another one is on bottom. There is blank space between them. How do I remove that blank? Additionally, how can I make all content to be as wide as `\textwidth`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{
        scale only axis,
        enlargelimits=false,
        width=0.4\textwidth,
        height=2cm,
        xmin=0.5,
        xmax=16.5,
        xticklabel=\empty,
        xtick={1,2,...,16},
        leftinnery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style=green!75!black,
            ytick style=green!75!black,
            ylabel=a,
            ylabel style=green!75!black,
            axis y line*=left,
            y axis line style=green!75!black,
            },
        rightinnery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style=blue,
            ytick style=blue,
            ylabel=b,
            ylabel style=blue,
            axis y line*=right,
            y axis line style=blue,
            },
        leftoutery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style={red,xshift=-1.7cm},
            ytick style={red,xshift=-1.7cm},
            ylabel=c,
            ylabel style=red,
            axis y line*=left,
            y axis line style={red,xshift=-1.7cm},
            },
        rightoutery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style={brown,xshift=1.4cm},
            ytick style={brown,xshift=1.4cm},
            ylabel=d,
            ylabel style=brown,
            axis y line*=right,
            y axis line style={brown,xshift=1.4cm},
            },
        }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[leftinnery]
                \addplot[green!75!black, mark=o, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   10
                    };
                \node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {东湖};
            \end{axis}            
            \begin{axis}[rightinnery]
                \addplot[blue, mark=x, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   2
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[leftoutery]
                \addplot[red, mark=+, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   1000
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[rightoutery]
                \addplot[brown, mark=Mercedes star, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   3
                    };
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
     \begin{tikzpicture}[yshift=-\lineskip]
            \begin{axis}[leftinnery]
                \addplot[green!75!black, mark=o, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   400
                    };
                \node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {东湖};
            \end{axis}            
            \begin{axis}[rightinnery]
                \addplot[blue, mark=x, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   2
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[leftoutery]
                \addplot[red, mark=+, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   3
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[rightoutery]
                \addplot[brown, mark=Mercedes star, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   40
                    };
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

It seems there a little blank space to the left of the figure, so the figure is a little bit to the right. How can I remove this blank space too? How to align all the labels and y axes? I guess it is difficult. Using **groupplot** may do these, but how to draw multiple y axes?

Comment: Have you considered using PGFPlots' `groupplot` environment for this task? It may also help to simplify your work, because currently, you're using eight different axis environments across two Ti*k*Z picture environments just to create a single graph.

Comment: @gz839918 I don't know how to merge `groupplot` with multiple y axes.

Comment: Have you read [reference manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for `pgfplots`? You'd probably have more options stacking two plots inside `pfgplots` and have more control over margins (guess). You could try to append `inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt` to `tikzpicture`s options but I doubt it will have a good effect. Finally, try to make a custom style and avoid repetitions. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270126/31283) provides example on using multiple parameters in custom styles.

Comment: @Celdor Not work: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/inner sep', to which 
you passed '0pt', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` . Let me check it now.

Comment: @Y.zeng `inner sep` and `outer sep` are keys in `/tikz/` namespace and are usually used to set inner and outer margins for `tikz` nodes. I meant to append them in `tikzpicture` in the following way: `\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]...\end{tikzpicture}`. However, I tested it and it doesn't work anyway. You could also have a look at section _4.20 The Picture’s Size: Bounding Box and Clipping_ of the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and see if you could reduce bounding box to inner axes.

Comment: @Celdor  If we don't know what is it of the left, we can't clip it perfectly.

Comment: @cfr Yes. I think you are right. I have deleted the updated contents. Thanks for your kind reminder.

Comment: @Y.zeng Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use `scope` instead of a new `tikzpicture`.  I aligned the y lables using `ylabel absolute` which also put all the labels on top  of each other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{
        scale only axis,
        enlargelimits=false,
        width=0.4\textwidth,
        height=2cm,
        xmin=0.5,
        xmax=16.5,
        xticklabel=\empty,
        xtick={1,2,...,16},
        ylabel absolute,
        leftinnery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style=green!75!black,
            ytick style=green!75!black,
            ylabel=a,
            ylabel style=green!75!black,
            axis y line*=left,
            y axis line style=green!75!black,
            },
        rightinnery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style=blue,
            ytick style=blue,
            ylabel=b,
            ylabel style={blue, yshift=\dimexpr -0.4\textwidth-2.1cm},% 2.1cm by trial and error
            axis y line*=right,
            y axis line style=blue,
            },
        leftoutery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style={red,xshift=-1.7cm},
            ytick style={red,xshift=-1.7cm},
            ylabel=c,
            ylabel style={red,yshift=1.7cm},
            ylabel shift=-1.7cm,
            axis y line*=left,
            y axis line style={red,xshift=-1.7cm},
            },
        rightoutery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style={brown,xshift=1.4cm},
            ytick style={brown,xshift=1.4cm},
            ylabel=d,
            ylabel style={brown, yshift=\dimexpr -0.4\textwidth-2.1cm-1.4cm},
            axis y line*=right,
            y axis line style={brown,xshift=1.4cm},
            },
        }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \begin{axis}[leftinnery]
                \addplot[green!75!black, mark=o, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   10
                    };
                \node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {东湖};
            \end{axis}            
            \begin{axis}[rightinnery]
                \addplot[blue, mark=x, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   2
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[leftoutery]
                \addplot[red, mark=+, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   1000
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[rightoutery]
                \addplot[brown, mark=Mercedes star, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   3
                    };
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
            \begin{axis}[leftinnery]
                \addplot[green!75!black, mark=o, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   400
                    };
                \node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {东湖};
            \end{axis}            
            \begin{axis}[rightinnery]
                \addplot[blue, mark=x, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   2
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[leftoutery]
                \addplot[red, mark=+, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   3
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[rightoutery]
                \addplot[brown, mark=Mercedes star, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   40
                    };
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: deno]

Comment: Thanks. How did you know the space between them is 2cm, as you take this way of `\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]`. And if there are three figures in a  column, how to deal with it? I tried to add a new `scope` block, but the second the third will overlap each other. Is there away to align the labels of axes?

Comment: Okay. I know how to deal with it. Every time, just add `-2cm` . Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to align the y axes labels?

Comment: I got the 2cm from the [scale only axis, height-2cm].  Aligning the y labels is possible, but I'll have to check the manual.  Worst case, add a node using (axis rel cs:).