# Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfkeyscurrentkey. ... fill=#2!#3, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

According to the answer of @percusse [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231701/tikzset-key-with-multiple-arguments), I am trying to define a multi-argument `\tikzstyle` as below

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{mystyle/.style n args{3}{circle, minimum size=#1 cm, draw=#2, fill=#2!#3, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}
    
    \node[mystyle={1}{red}{70}] (mynode) {};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfkeyscurrentkey. ... fill=#2!#3, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: You forgot an equal sign, as in `...style n args={3}{circle...`

Comment: @JuanCastaño: Late night, and silly mistakes! Thanks...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is solved in the comments